# Deadlock with Reorganize Index

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, columnstore, index-maintenance

I was running `alter index reorganize` on some columnstore indexes in SQL Server 2016 and got a deadlock message.

Will `reorganize` always be the victim? Because I do not want to cause other jobs to fail and I am thinking to add a `set deadlock_priority`. Or is this built-in for the `alter index` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not documented to have a particular deadlock priority, and it does make data changes.  So you should explicitly set a deadlock priority, and perhaps a retry loop, to enforce the behavior and document it.

REORGANIZE is an "online" operation, which means it doesn't take a big Sch-M lock at the beginning of the operation to have exclusive access.  And moreover it's perhaps the only DDL statement that is non-transactional.  IE it commits little bits of work as it goes to avoid holding long-lived locks.  If you trace the locking behavior you'll see something like:

[image]